# Copy randomly generated text from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, text, vbscript, copy

Currently I am working on vbs that opens a webpage, enters a login, logs in, enters some information, and receives a randomly generated CD Key.

Is there any way I can copy this CD key? using `ie.document.getelementbyid` I cant find any ID Associated with the CD key, only with the whole text box containing the CD Key.

Is there any way to specify precisely where on the webpage what I want is? Like choose the text I want to copy from the line its on in the website?

The CD key is always random. The only constant is it will be in a cell, and it has hyphens (like any CD Key)

I just need to extract the CD Key so I can store it in a text file etc. like in the example below

[image: Example]

Edit:

Code so far:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
 IE.Visible = 1    
 IE.navigate "xxxx" 
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 100    
 Loop    
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("UserNameTextBox") 
 Helem.Value = "xxxxx"    
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("PasswordTextBox")
 Helem.Value = "xxxxx"   
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("Button1")
 Helem.Click
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 100    
 Loop  
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_PackageDropdown")
Helem.Value = "430"
IE.Document.getElementByID("generateECodes_PackageDropdown").FireEvent ("onChange")
WScript.Sleep 500
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_TermDropdown")
Helem.Value = "5"
IE.Document.getElementByID("generateECodes_TermDropdown").FireEvent ("onChange")
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Languages")
Helem.Value = "29"
IE.Document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Languages").FireEvent ("onChange")
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_StoreNumber")
Helem.Value = "230"
IE.Document.getElementByID("generateECodes_StoreNumber").FireEvent ("onChange")
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Required")
 Helem.Value = "1" 
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Button")
 Helem.Click
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 500    
 Loop  
   Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Table")


 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 100    
 Loop  

dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile("c:\Something.txt", True) 
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:\Something.txt") 
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path) 
filetxt.WriteLine("Password: "+Helem) 
filetxt.WriteLine("Brugernavn: "+Helem) 
filetxt.Close
```

Comment: Here is a pic of the code where the X's represent the key code i need to extract. http://i59.tinypic.com/4kz47m.png

Comment: Show us what you have so far so the community has something to work with. Right now it looks like you are asking for a code writing service which is not what SO is here for.

Comment: Sorry. Was having issues posting it, and im at Work and this doesnt have the highest priority :P Ive edited in the code above. The last bit, Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Table"), is what im having issues with. Extracting the content of that table into a txt file, preferably only extracting the required information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the `<td>` elements from the table you already fetched, and check if the `innerText` matches the pattern for a CD key:

```
...
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("generateECodes_Table")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\w{5}(-\w{5}){4}"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each td In Helem.getElementsByTagName("td")
  If re.Test(td.innerText) Then cdKey = td.innerText
Next
...
```

Comment: That..is..Beautiful! Thanks a ton. I should probably start reading up on some RE.. I suck at that. Any recommended guides? Works perfectly.